# Getting the location of the maximum coefficient of an Eigen C++ library Vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I came across a problem due to either my misunderstanding of the
documentation, or a bug.

I want to retrieve the position of the maximum coefficient of a vector:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Eigen::Vector3f v;
  int pos;

  v <<  1, 2, 3;

  std::cout << v.maxCoeff(&pos) << "\n" << "pos=" <<  pos << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

the returned result (pos) is always zero, no matter where the maximum
value is.  Through debugging, I have seen that indeed the correct value
(i, j) is computed in the visitor, but it seems that maxVisitor.col is
returned instead of maxVisitor.row.

This happens also with the latest mercurial version.

Do you think it is a bug?  Should I file a bug report?

Comment: `Should I file a bug report?` I highly doubt that a library that is on its third major version would be tripped up by such a simple example.  That `cout` line uses pos before it is initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no sequence point between the 2 uses of `pos` in your line. The compiler is free to evaluate the second `pos` before calling `maxCoeff`. If you initialize `int pos = 42;` it will make it more obvious.